# Is the absence of complex analysis a significant disadvantage in math grad school application?

Tags: undergraduate-education, probability, applications

I am a junior math major considering math grad school, possibly in probability theory. Would the admission commitee of math grad schools view the absence of complex analysis as a significant disadvantage?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. You might want to try: http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But my personal experience would suggest "no" since Complex Analysis was a common first-year-graduate course at both my undergrad and graduate institutions.

Comment: It would be best to cite & link to your previous question: [Soft question: take complex analysis or cryptology?](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10421/511).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. As already remarked, you may wish to check if the question is on-topic for academia.stackexchange.com.